# (tensorflow) Is it possible to combine GridLSTM and MLP/CNN?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to train on images using GridLSTM and MLP/CNN.

So basically what I would like to try is to input an image into a GridLSTM and then take its output and feed into MLP/CNN as the next layer.

e.g.:

```
2-D image -> GridLSTM -> MLP or CNN -> GridLSTM -> MLP or CNN -> Output
```

I tried running the example code of GridLSTM and the tutorial on Cifar10 (for CNN).

But the input and output for both examples are in a different type (list for GridLSTM and tensor for CNN).

And I was wondering whether it is possible to combine GridLSTM and MLP/CNN at the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in "Scene Labeling with LSTM Recurrent Neural Networks", I believe the feedforward layer takes as input the output of LSTM layers at **every step**. Assuming that the LSTM layers give you a list of N outputs, you will then need to iterate through this list, and apply the feedforward layer to every element of the list.

This is why in Figure 1 of the paper, you see blocks of `3xnxn` in the LSTM layer mapped to a block of size `1x1` in the Feedforward layer. You will need to iterate through the whole image in order to compute the whole output for the Feedforward layer. This also explains why they used LSTM and feedforward layers of only a few dozens of units.

Now, how to implement that in Tensorflow is up to you. You can use [tf.scan()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#scan) to iterate through the list of tensor given by LSTM, and apply the feedforward layer on each of the element; or you can concat the tensors in the list with [tf.concat()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#concat) and apply a convolutional operation with suitable sizes. Depending on your network, one way can be faster than the other.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi Vu Pham, thank you so much for your time writing the answer. i tried tf.cancat() and applied convolutional operation by modifying Cifar10 tutorial and it seems to work well. i was wondering if backpropagation and optimization supported by tensorflow will still work after combining rnn and cnn modules. i'm glad to know that it works! thanks again for your help, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to a colleague involved in the GridLSTM implementation, and here is her reply:

---

You can't. So the LSTM will remove the correlation in time-freq so I don't think you can pass it to a convolutional layer. That being said, you can have multiple grid LSTM layers. See this as an example.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/TFLSTM-1.pdf

Comment: thank you for your comment! actually i'm trying to implement the "Scene Labeling with LSTM Recurrent Neural Networks" (http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Byeon_Scene_Labeling_With_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf). They used 2D-LSTM network but I was planning to replace 2D-LSTM with GridLSTM since it seems like the latter is a newer version of former. They used "fully-connected layer" right after 2D-LSTM layer, which I thought I could use fully-connected layer in MLP/CNN module in Tensorflow. Is it impossible to implement the paper using Tensorflow?